# Convert GiNaC harmonic polylogarithms to HPL packages' notation in Mathematica

Tags: import, special-functions, string-manipulation, packages, conversion

A general output from GiNaC (https://www.ginac.de/) of  harmonic polylogarithms is `H(a,b,c...,x)`. We want to convert it to Mathematica format (https://www.physik.uzh.ch/data/HPL/) `HPL[{a,b,c...},x]`.

Note: we need "a general string expression" for the "a,b,c..." in
`H(a,b,c...,x)` as we have to deal with a lot of `H`s, for example, converting:

```
H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)
```

to

```
HPL[{2,2},x],HPL[{1,2},x],HPL[{1,2,3},x],HPL[{1,2,3,4},x],HPL[{1,2,3,4,5},x]
```

Comment: Does something like `StringCases["H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)", RegularExpression["H\\(([\\w,]+)\\)?"] :> With[{res = ToExpression /@ StringSplit["$1", ","]}, HPL[Most[res], Last[res]]]]` work for you?

Comment: How arbitrary is "arbitrary"?

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Ah! I see thank you for you code. My problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general solution: We treat the input as a string, use `StringReplace` to make the necessary replacements and then add braces, so that we can change it to a MMA list:

```
str = StringReplace[
  "H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)" , 
  "H(" ~~ a : Except[")"] .. ~~ ")" -> "HPL[" ~~ a ~~ "]"]  

ToExpression["{" <> str <> "}"]
```

This gives:

```
{HPL[2, 2, x], HPL[2, 1, x], HPL[2, 1, 2, x], HPL[1, 2, 3, 4, x], HPL[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, x]}
```

Comment: The first few should be in a list, and separated from the last one.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui I fixed this `str = StringReplace[
  "H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)", 
  "H(" ~~ a : Except[")"] .. ~~ ",x)" -> "HPL[{" ~~ a ~~ "},x]"]`

Comment: @YU `StringCases[]` would still be the better route if you don't like regexes like in my previous comment: `StringCases["H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)", "H(" ~~ a : Except[")"] .. ~~ ")" :> With[{r = ToExpression /@ StringSplit[a, ","]}, HPL[Most[r], Last[r]]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

A related, but potentially more flexible approach than Daniel Huber's. First do the most minimal transformations necessary to allow Mathematica to interpret this as an expression

```
hexpr = "H(2,2,x),H(2,1,x),H(2,1,2,x),H(1,2,3,4,x),H(1,2,3,4,5,x)" // 
   StringReplace[{"(" -> "[", ")" -> "]"}] // ToExpression["{" <> # <> "}"] &

{H[2, 2, x], H[2, 1, x], H[2, 1, 2, x], H[1, 2, 3, 4, x], H[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, x]}
```

then use Mathematica's symbolic manipulation tools to transform this into the desired output

```
hexpr // ReplaceAll[
  H[args__, var_] :> HPL[{args}, var]
  ]

{HPL[{2, 2}, x], HPL[{2, 1}, x], HPL[{2, 1, 2}, x], HPL[{1, 2, 3, 4}, x], 
 HPL[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, x]}
```

basically the idea is to delegate all of the string parsing effort to Mathematica, if possible, and then just transform it using standard methods

Comment: Beautiful code! I understand. Thank you @b3m2a1